# Google places v3 getDetails in specific language

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In my Application, I need to find a place over the Google Places Autocomplete function. This function returns the location Country, Region, City, etc. These fields are returned in the language passed in the function call.

In a next step, I want the result to be translated.

My approach was to use the location reference returned by the Autocomplete function to call getDetails for every language, but when I use the library, the language parameter is ignored.

I prefer to use the library, because I do not need a client key.

```
var request = {
        reference: place.reference,
        language: lang
      };
service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {});
```

Comment: I'd like to know this as well!

Comment: @tonio and svoop - Is there a more clearer question that you can put into the question. Something like "How can I ...?" at the end of the question can help answerers better.